# cant add more menus to wordpress custom menus

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I tried to add a custom menu in wordpress menu. My menu limit to 90 and can not be added again.

I've been following the various ways below but it did not work

```
<IfModule mod_php.c> 
php_value suhosin.simulation 1 
</ IfModule>
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following has worked for some users with similar problem:
>
> Try to increase the value of the max_input_vars variable in php.ini.
> This variable was introduced in PHP version 5.3.9 and has the default
> value of 1000.
>
> You can read more about it in the PHP documentation:
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php
>
> max_input_vars  1000    PHP_INI_PERDIR  Available since PHP 5.3.9.
>
> How
> many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET,
> $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive
> mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash
> collisions.
>
> You could try to increase it to 1500 or 2000.

source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96587/menu-items-disappearing/96593#96593

Answer (score 0):

I found Solution! Just add max_input_vars = 5000 on php.ini at the first line